# ORA-01017: invalid username/password via dblink

Tags: oracle, dblink

I've some problem with procedure which select data via dblink

I can select source tables normally and procedure compiles successfully but when I run this procedure I receive error

```
create or replace procedure proc1 is
begin

  execute immediate 'truncate table table1';

  INSERT /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING PARALLEL */
  INTO table1
         SELECT smthng
              FROM table1@dblink uo
              LEFT JOIN table2@dblink uoc
                ON uoc.id = uo.id
              LEFT JOIN table3@dblink uos
                ON uos.id = uoc.id;
  COMMIT;


end;

SQL> execute proc1 
begin proc1; end;
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-02063: предшествующий line из dblink 
ORA-06512: на  "proc1", line 8
ORA-06512: на  line 1
```

Any explanations?

Comment: How many listener do you see for `dblink lsnrctl` when you issue `lsnrctl status` from command prompt of your OS?

Comment: So you mean to say when you do `Select * from table1@dblink ` it produces result but when you execute the procedure, it throws error.

Comment: yes, exactly @XING

Comment: are you logged in as the same user as the procedure owner when you do the select?  sometimes there is a public db link and a private link both with the same name.  Also, sometimes the db link does not have the user credentials in it so it depends on who is using the link

Answer (score 1):

To give a solution on this question you need to know which version of Oracle database you are using, you need to explain us how the database link is being created. Is it a public link ? Is it anonymous ? What is the DOP (degree of parallelisme) specified on ALL tables used in your query. Who is executing the query ? Is it the same user that your are using via a remote database link ? Is this user having the same password as the one executing the query locally ?

I can make it even worse : do you use an ops$-account externally identified ? Or is this last one assigned a password ?

And last but NOT LEAST check via the auditing tables if the users that cannot logon to the remote database. Tell me is this the same user you are using with your local query ?